# Need algorithm for proportional value distributions between weighted buckets

Tags: algorithm, math, bucket

Seems I have problem like [Algorithm for constrained proportional distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46625037/algorithm-for-constrained-proportional-distribution) but I can't expand solution to my task.

Assume we have X weighted buckets (for example 30000, 17000, 60000) and values Y (for example 2000, 3000, 5000, 8000, 9000, 11000). In matrix all values are marked if they can be distributed to bucket (1 - allowed, 0 - not allowed).
We need do distribute values to buckets so the proportions will be as equal as it possible. In this case we will distribute 10000 for 30000 bucket (33%), 8000 for 17000 bucket (47%) and 20000 for 60000 bucket (33%).

My algorithm is:

1. We take values that can be allocated only to 1 bucket and allocate them. Calculate proportion. (5000 for 30000 (16%), 8000 for 17000 (47%) and 11000 for 60000(18%))

2.1. Take values that can be allocated to 2 buckets. Take bucket with min allocation of this two after step 1. Try to fill it with part-values so it will have same proportion as 2nd bucket. Value 3000 can be allocated to 30000 and 17000. At this moment 30000 has 16% and 17000 has 47% so we try to put 3000 to 30000, it will have (5000+3000)/30000 = 26% allocation. Still less than 47%, it's ok. If it will be more than 47% we will fill up to 47% and distribute excess equally between 30000 and 17000 proportionally.

2.2. Take another pair of buckets. And so on. Until we will distribute all 2-bucket values.

3. Take values that can be allocated to 3 buckets. Check min proportion, fill it up to the next. After fill them equally to the 3rd with excess values.
   Continue until all values will be distributed.

I have feelings that we can get situation where order of distribution (for example 3000->2000 or 2000->3000) can give us different result. So we need to do another steps to avoid that. In this task we don't have any constraints, we only want at the end equal proportions (or as close as possible).
Any help with theory for this task? Or may be another algorithm.

Data to check with:
,0,1,2,3,4,5
0,0,9000,9000,4500,4500,1000
1,1000,1,1,1,1,0
2,1000,1,1,1,1,0
3,1000,1,1,1,1,0
4,1000,1,1,1,1,0
5,1000,1,1,1,1,0
6,1000,1,1,1,1,0
7,1000,1,1,1,1,0
8,1000,1,1,1,1,0
9,1000,1,1,1,1,0
10,1000,0,0,0,0,1
and expect to get result:
0.33,0.33,0.17,0.17
,0,1,2,3,4,5
0,0,9000,9000,4500,4500,1000
1,1000,0.33,0.33,0.17,0.17,0
2,1000,0.33,0.33,0.17,0.17,0
3,1000,0.33,0.33,0.17,0.17,0
4,1000,0.33,0.33,0.17,0.17,0
5,1000,0.33,0.33,0.17,0.17,0
6,1000,0.33,0.33,0.17,0.17,0
7,1000,0.33,0.33,0.17,0.17,0
8,1000,0.33,0.33,0.17,0.17,0
9,1000,0.33,0.33,0.17,0.17,0
10,1000,0,0,0,0,1
so we will have one bucket filled for 100%(1000 bucket) and 4 buckets filled equally up to 33%.

Check the algorithm below.

```html
Matrix example
<table>
<tr>
<th>value</th>
<th>30000</th>
<th>17000</th>
<th>60000</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>2000</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>1</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>3000</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>0</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>5000</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>0</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>8000</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>0</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>9000</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>1</th>
<th>1</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>11000</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>0</th>
<th>1</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to distribute all values? Otherwise you could just distribute no values and have equal ratio of 0%

Comment: @maraca Unfortunately need to distribute all values =(

Comment: In the literature, this would be classified as a parallel machine scheduling problem, specifically minimizing the makespan (~ max filled proportion) of general jobs (~ values, "general" because they are not identical) on uniformly related machines (~ buckets, where speed ~ bucket weight) with machine eligibility restrictions (~ the 0-1 matrix). Unfortunately this generalizes several NP-hard problems, making it itself NP-hard. Are you more interested in guaranteed fast processing or the best solution?

Comment: David, I need best solution. Matrix will not exceed 25x50 i think.

Comment: So not trivial but small. Seems doable. Any chance you could share one of the largest instances you care about?

Comment: Don't have them, but can synthetically generate them.

Comment: That would be helpful since it can be difficult to tell a priori how much engineering is required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223051/discussion-between-andrey-and-david-eisenstat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is in Python 3 and uses the [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/python) library.

```
# reads the CSV export of the .xlsx files, writes CSV to stdout

import csv
import fileinput
import sys

from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

# read the input
rows = list(csv.reader(fileinput.input()))
values = [float(row[1]) for row in rows[2:-1]]
buckets = [float(cell) for cell in rows[1][2:-1]]
eligible_member = [[int(cell) for cell in row[2:-1]] for row in rows[2:-1]]

# the solver must have good symmetry breaking, else this formulation is bad
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("solver", "SCIP")

# minimize the max fill ratio minus the min fill ratio
max_fill_ratio = solver.NumVar(0, solver.infinity(), "")
min_fill_ratio = solver.NumVar(0, solver.infinity(), "")
solver.Objective().SetMinimization()
solver.Objective().SetCoefficient(max_fill_ratio, 1)
solver.Objective().SetCoefficient(min_fill_ratio, -1)

# fractional indicator variables -- indicators[i][j] is the fraction of value i
# assigned to bucket j
indicators = [[solver.NumVar(0, cell, "") for cell in row] for row in eligible_member]

# ensure that each value is exactly 100% assigned
for i, value in enumerate(values):
    exact_cover_constraint = solver.Constraint(1, 1)
    for j, bucket in enumerate(buckets):
        exact_cover_constraint.SetCoefficient(indicators[i][j], 1)

# the usual trick for minimizing a maximum -- constrain it to be greater than or
# equal to each value maximized over, let the solver do the rest
for j, bucket in enumerate(buckets):
    max_load_constraint = solver.Constraint(-solver.infinity(), 0)
    max_load_constraint.SetCoefficient(max_fill_ratio, -1)
    min_load_constraint = solver.Constraint(0, solver.infinity())
    min_load_constraint.SetCoefficient(min_fill_ratio, -1)
    for i, value in enumerate(values):
        ratio = value / bucket
        max_load_constraint.SetCoefficient(indicators[i][j], ratio)
        min_load_constraint.SetCoefficient(indicators[i][j], ratio)

# enable to diagnose slowness
if False:
    solver.EnableOutput()

if solver.Solve() != solver.OPTIMAL:
    raise RuntimeError
w = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
w.writerow([solver.Objective().Value()] + buckets)
for i, value in enumerate(values):
    w.writerow([value] + [indicator.solution_value() for indicator in indicators[i]])
```

Comment: Need to understand code. But due to comment # ensure that each value is assigned to exactly one bucket - can't we split values between buckets? In the task we can, tried to show it in "If it will be more than 47% we will fill up to 47% and distribute excess equally between 30000 and 17000 proportionally.".

Comment: Thank you, I tried this code. Seems it solves another task. I checked with:  
,0,1,2  
0,0,25000,56000  
1,15000,0,1  
2,30000,1,1  
and expect to get result:  
,0,1,2  
0,0,25000,56000  
1,15000,0,15000  
2,30000,13888.8,16111.1  
so 15000 value fully allocated to 56000 bucket and 30000 value splitted up.  
But solver gives:  
0.8035714285714286,25000.0,56000.0  
15000.0,0.0,1.0  
30000.0,0.0,1.0  
It allocates all values to 56000 bucket.

Comment: @Andrey oh, change that `solver.IntVar` to `solver.NumVar` then.

Comment: Tested. If we have a value assigned to one bucket and value fills bucket for a big value, solver tries to fill all other buckets up to that value. So we can have situation when we have only 2 buckets filled when we can have more filled buckets but for a less amount. Gave example of data in description. I think we need to maximizing minimum than?

Comment: @Andrey ok, posted a new version that does just that.

Comment: seems now it works fine. But i have 3 questions: 1) Line solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("solver", "SCIP") calls error: CreateSolver() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given. I just changed to 1 argument "SCIP". Is it ok? 2) Why slices are [2:-1]? They lose last row, i changed to [2:]. 3) "the solver must have good symmetry" what does that mean?

Comment: @Andrey 1) Unsure, works for me, guess they changed the API. 2) The .xlsx file I looked at had sums of the matrix rows and columns in the last row and column. 3) Ignore the symmetry breaking remark; that was for the `IntVar` version. This one uses linear programming, so it'll be fast regardless.